# On a Silverlight 2 datagrid, how can I get a collection of only the rows that are edited?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-2.0

I load data into my grid using a WCF service.  When a user clicks 'Submit' on my silverlight 2 control, I want to send only the edited rows back to my WCF service for updating.  Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better if you monitor the changes on the source objects.  It would be easy to write a simple class to register for the changes using the INotifyPropertyChange and keep a list of changed objects (the sources).

Comment: thanks Shawn.  The class I am binding from implements INotifyPropertyChanged automatically.  Are you suggesting to write another class?  I'm not sure where that fits in